# Webpack & Testing: Helper to delete/replace modules from the require cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, webpack

For our tests we need to be able to replace or delete modules from the require cache, e.g. to replace them with a fake implementation.

In order to achieve this we implemented a little helper function:

```
fakeModule = function(modulePath, fakeExportsObject){
    require.cache[require.resolve(modulePath)] = {exports: fakeExportsObject}
}
```

However when we run this through webpack we get the following critical warning: "the request of a dependency is an expression" and **all** JavaScript files in the project are included in the webpack build.

Is there any possibility to disable the interpretation of the helper function? In our tests we can safely assume that we are only deleting/replacing existent modules from the require cache. Even if not, it wouldn´t really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) and [rewire-webpack](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire-webpack)? I just started looking into testing with webpack and will need to find a way to accomplish this as well. Rewire sounds promising, but I haven't used it yet.